# How to return just the first element in table? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code to get information from which table row was selected, how would I access just the first element (in this case, 2) and assign it to a variable?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#usersTable tr").click(function(){
    $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
  });
})
```

It returns the following in the console

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<table id="usersTable">
 <div id="div2">
 <tbody id="tableBody">
 <tr id="tableHeadings">
     <th>User ID</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Forename</th>
     <th>Surname</th>
     <th>Avatar</th>
 </tr>


 <tr id="row0">
     <td id="id0" title="User ID Number"></td>
     <td id="email0" title="User Email"></td>
     <td id="forename0" title="User Forename"></td>
     <td id="surname0" title="User Surname"></td>
     <td>
         <img id="image0"  title="User Image">
     </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: $(this).find("td")[0] is working?

Comment: Share the ```HTML``` syntax.

Comment: `this.querySelector("td").innerText`

Comment: @SajeebAhamed just edited my post

Comment: @Shubham sadly not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index` param of the `each` function. 
https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#usersTable tr").click(function(){
    $(this).find("td").each(function(index){
        if (index === 0) {
           console.log($(this).html());
         }

    });
  });
})
```

**If you don't need the other `td` elements, dont loop! Better use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176359/10781526) solution below.**

Comment: I changed the index that you gave to 0, and it worked perfectly, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

you can use a selector like this so it saves you from looping all the cells of the selected row

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#usersTable tr").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("td:first-child").html());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've restructured your HTML structure and update the javascript code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr').on('click', function() {
    let firstTd = $(this).find('td:first-child');
    let userId = firstTd.text();

    console.log(userId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="usersTable">
  <div id="div2">
     <thead>
       <tr id="tableHeadings">
         <th>User ID</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Forename</th>
         <th>Surname</th>
         <th>Avatar</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="tableBody">
       <tr id="row0">
           <td id="id0" title="User ID Number">2</td>
           <td id="email0" title="User Email">some@e.com</td>
           <td id="forename0" title="User Forename">demo</td>
           <td id="surname0" title="User Surname">doe</td>
           <td>img</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</table>
```